# How can I edit srf image files?

Tags: gimp, file-format, image-processing

I have a Garmin Nuvi GPS, which contains images, in dot SRF format. 
I would like to edit the images, or create new srf image files. I have tried to use GIMP to edit or export images to and from this format but I do not see support for it. Is there a package that supports editing this type of file in GIMP, or some other image editor?

Ubuntu Mate 17.10 is my OS.

Answer (score 2):

I tested with the following file:

```
wget http://rawsamples.ch/raws/sony/RAW_SONY_DSC-F828.SRF
```

Partial success on 2 fronts:

1. **Gimp:** This gui application will *import* these files, and subsequently allow *editing* but will not *export* to the .srf format unfortunately. This is done with the assistance of ufraw:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gimp gimp-ufraw
   ```
2. **ImageMagick:** This command line application easily *converts* .srf files to .png for subsequent editing, but not possible to subsequently *export* to .srf. A simple command line will accomplish conversion:

   ```
   convert RAW_SONY_DSC-F828.SRF test.png
   ```

So: easy to *read* and subsequently *edit* but less easy to *export* to srf in all applications that I have tested (including Krita if you want to try something a little different)...

Comment: I'll have to post my answer to this which was much more convoluted. the GPS may have srf files, but the ones i wrote using this gimp plug-in didnt work. other  factors like fixed image size could also have been an issue. In any case, I ended up converting the png files (or whatever) to srf using a hex editor, to modify the headers, and footers, to make an image that my gps would accept and use.